# Lagged Exogenous Variables in VECM with R

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration

Looking to estimate a `VARX(p,q)` type VECM in R if possible.

I'd like to estimate a VECM with p lags (lags relative to the level, not diff of the vars) on the endogenous variables and q lags on the exogenous components. Any ideas?  At the moment I'm using the `ca.jo()` function and adding the contemporaneous and lagged exogenous variables to the `dumvar=` option.  I do not feel confident about this approach.

Can I do this in R?  Should I switch software?

Answer (score 4):

If your variables are exogenous and their lags are exogenous, then there is no problem in treating them as dummy variables. So you can add them to `dumvar` option. My answer [to similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4030/finding-coefficients-for-vecm-exogenous-variables/5291#5291) applies.

Comment: There is no need to merge -- this is an example of "good duplicate"